# jQuery UI Class Names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a project where the CSS naming conventions employed aren't compatible with the class names that jQuery UI provides. Is there any way beyond a simple search/replace in the jQuery UI source (which sounds dangerous) to change the class names that jQuery UI provides for its elements?

For example, jQuery resizable requires handles with the class `.ui-resizable-handle`, when it should be `.resizeHandle`.

Comment: Could you use jquery to change the class as soon as it get's applied, like: 

$("#elementId").removeClass().addClass("myClass");

Comment: Well, yeah, I could, but it would screw up jQuery UI's internal stuff, which relies on its classes being present. So I would have to tell jUI about the change somehow, but that's what the OP is about.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to camelize the jQuery UI class names truncating the "ui-" part.

If so, you can do something like this -

```
 $('*[class^=ui-]').toggleClass(function (index, classNamesToChange) {
     $.each(classNamesToChange.split(' '), function(index, classNameToChange){
         return classNameToChange[3].toLowerCase() + 
               classNameToChange.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (a, b) {
                    return b.toUpperCase();
         }).slice(3);
      });
 });
```

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/78GM5/3/

**EDIT** If you would like to map the camel cased class names to corresponding styles, you can try this. Get the style for the class name using the following.

```
 function css(a) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules) {
            if (a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {                    
                o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}

function css2json(css) {
    var s = {};
    if (!css) return s;
    if (css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
        for (var i in css) {
            if ((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
            }
        }
    } else if (typeof css == "string") {
        css = css.split("; ");
        for (var i in css) {
            var l = css[i].split(": ");
            s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

The above piece of code is from this awesome thread - [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

And then use this code to write it into a style.

```
  $('*[class^=ui-]').toggleClass(function (index, classNamesToChange) {
        $.each(classNamesToChange.split(' '), function(index, classNameToChange){
            var originalClassName = classNameToChange;
            var classNameToReturn = classNameToChange[3].toLowerCase() + classNameToChange.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (a, b) {
                return b.toUpperCase();
            }).slice(3); 

            $('style').append('.' + classNameToReturn + JSON.stringify(css($('.' + originalClassName))) );

            return classNameToReturn;               
        });            
    });
```

This won't work in jsfiddle for obvious reasons. But just a thought..

Here is the fiddle for this - http://jsfiddle.net/78GM5/6/

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I'm trying to do. I need to change not only the class names present in the DOM, but also the class names that jUI relies on internally. Changing just the class names results in this: http://jsfiddle.net/78GM5/5/ (note that the draggable is broken when you actually click the anchor)

Comment: Well.. Good luck trying not to do Search and Replace! :) I cannot think of any other way you'd camelize the class names in a CSS file (unless there is a cool CSS file camelizer / parser that I didn't know about)